# database design: schema changes based on year?

Tags: database, database-design, oracle11g, database-schema

there is a particular piece of data in my dataset that will most likely change given
the year (fiscal year to be exact).  how can a piece of data like this be accounted for
in a database schema?  for instance, i have set up a couple of fields based on the year (XYZ_2009, XYZ_2010) but i'm afraid that the database table will become elongated and cumbersome to maintain (having to add a new field every year).  is this the preferred way to
handle this type of problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the data and your current schema. Its hard to pick up anything from the little-to-none information you have provided here.

Comment: Can you tag the question with the database engine you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need have a new field each year? I'd go the route of a new table that is a one to many from the main table:

```
tblMain
PriKeyMain, Field1, Field2, XYZ_2009, XYZ_2010, XYZ_2011, ABC_2009, ABC_2010, ABC_2011
```

becomes:

```
tblMain
PriKeyMain, Field1, Field2

tblDetail
PriKeyDetail, PriKeyMain, Year, XYZ, ABC
```